# WebSphere 6.1 use OracleConnection object while still demanding connection management to the WAS

Tags: database, oracle, connection, websphere

We're working with a WebSphere 6.1 application server and an Oracle 10g database.

We were asked to demand the DB connection management to the WAS but we must also use an OracleConnection object to properly work with our DB.

In detail, we get the **com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.wsjdbcconnection incompatible with oracle.jdbc.oracleconnection** error if we stick with WebSphere's connection object.

Googling around suggested that we use the *getNativeConnection* method like so:

```
WSJdbcConnection conn = (WSJdbcConnection) ds.getConnection();
con = (OracleConnection) WSJdbcUtil.getNativeConnection((WSJdbcConnection) conn);
```

But then the connection would no longer be managed by WebSphere.

Is there any way to work with an Oracle connection object while still having WebSphere manage the DB connections?

Thank you,

best regards

EDIT: I was even asked not to use the WSCallHelper class

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [WSCallHelper API](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/rdat_levport.html) is what you are looking for.

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention it but they asked me to avoid it. I'll edit now, thank you anyway

Comment: What is the reason for that?

Comment: The application runs fine on other webservers/databases without the WSCallHelper API, and introducing it would imply massive recoding and testing. Obviously, I was asked to look for the quickest and less troublesome solution. Furthermore, we are already able to perform certain operations on the Oracle database without that class.